# Firebase reverse dns lookup ENOTFOUND error node.js dns

Tags: node.js, firebase, dns, google-cloud-functions

Hello Stackoverflow community! :)

I have a cloud function running on Firebase, which serves as an API and there is another server (fitbit.com), which occasionally POSTs data to my server.

As one of the security features, I'd like to do a Forward-Confirmed Reverse DNS, which is basically the following:

1. I receive a POST on an endpoint from IP 169.45.142.104.
2. I do a reverse DNS lookup to retrieve the hostname of the server.
3. Verify that this returns a subdomain of fitbit.com (the IP in the example should resolve into ['api-169-45-141-216.fitbit.com']).
4. Then, I do a DNS lookup on that hostname and verify if it resolves
   to the IP address of the original request.

Here's the source code written for node v6.11.1 (it's in a Util class.. :))

```
static fcrDns(ipAddress, cb) {
        const reverse = Q.denodeify(dns.reverse);
        const resolve4 = Q.denodeify(dns.resolve4);
        return reverse(ipAddress).then(hostNames => {
            console.log("hostNames: ", hostNames);

            if (!hostNames.every(SecurityUtils._isFitbitSubDomain)) {
                return Promise.reject("Hostname did not end with .fitbit.com");
            } else {
                return Promise.all([...hostNames.map(hostName => {
                    return resolve4(hostName)
                        .then(resolvedAddresses => {
                            if (resolvedAddresses.every(address => address === ipAddress)) {
                                return Promise.resolve(true);
                            } else {
                                return Promise.reject("Resolved address did not equal to initial IP address");
                            }
                        })
                })]);
            }
        });
    }

    static _isFitbitSubDomain(hostName) {
        return hostName.endsWith(".fitbit.com");
    };
```

Now, the problem is: this works perfectly if I do firebase serve --only functions on localhost, both on windows and linux hosts.

However, once it's deployed to Firebase and executed, I get the following error:

```
{ Error: getHostByAddr ENOTFOUND 169.45.142.104
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:219:19)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getHostByAddr',
  hostname: '169.45.142.104' }
```

Which, as far as I understood node's source code it means that it could not perform reverse IP lookup.

However, as I've tested, resolving the hostname works properly.

Might there be a server setting, which could prevent doing reverse dns lookup, but allows resolving?

Comment: What payment plan is you Firebase project on?

Comment: It is on Flame Plan

Comment: Interesting, I'll file a bug internally. Normally we open up IPs based on DNS lookup and allow them if the user is on a paid plan or if the DNS address is a whitelisted Google API. Reverse DNS seems like a reasonable use case and we should look into what can be done.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input and help @ThomasBouldin! I have edited my question with the complete error response I get, maybe it will help tracing the error. Otherwise, please do let me know if I can provide any more information or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked to the Cloud Functions backend team, and they currently don't allow reverse DNS lookups.  This is something that could be changed, so I will encourage you to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with the details of why this is important to you.  Also provide a link to this issue on SO.

EDIT: It looks like the change was made to allow this, but it's not clear to me if it's already available, or when it will be made available.

Comment: As a reply to the EDIT: I still get the the original error response as of now, so let's hope the feature will make it live at some point. :)

Comment: @ZoltánTudlik I'm able to reverse DNS OK in a simple function that does nothing but that.  Project is on the Blaze plan.

Comment: Indeed, I've just checked it today and indeed the feature is now working. Thanks a lot for your work guys!

Comment: @ZoltánTudlik Seems like it might be disabled again? I am seeing the ENOTFOUND error mentionedi in the question.

Comment: @ChrisChiasson I'm not sure, sorry, I'm no longer working with Firebase actively.