# Testing prerender.io middleware for angular application hosted on firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, prerender

I have Angular application hosted on Firebase and trying to use prerender.io to improve its SEO.

Here is a pretty straightforward set up for prerender.io middleware I deploy using firebase functions

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'myToken'));
app.get('**', function (req, res) {
 res.sendFile('dist/browser/index.html', {'root': '.'});
});
export const myApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

`prerender-node` middleware prerenders pages only for crawlers requests. Unfortunately, during first days no crawlers made request to my application, so I want to test it myself.

There is how I tried to simulate a crawler call. I took a look into `prerender-node` source code and saw that there is a method `shouldShowPrerenderedPage` that makes a check by `user-agent` HTTP header whether the request done by crawler.

I have made http GET request to my application with `User-Agent=googlebot` and got an error

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND service.prerender.io service.prerender.io:443
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

If I remove header everything works fine but no prerendering happens.

Has anybody experienced the same issue?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it tried to lookup the DNS for https://service.prerender.io and it failed. It looks like Firebase might not allow DNS lookups by default? [Firebase reverse dns lookup ENOTFOUND error node.js dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548085/firebase-reverse-dns-lookup-enotfound-error-node-js-dns)

Comment: I see the last comment to the correct answer there saying:
"Indeed, I've just checked it today and indeed the feature is now working. Thanks a lot for your work guys!"

Comment: Is it a feature that you have to enable or behind a paid plan or something? I haven't tested it myself so I'm not sure what's going on there that would cause that DNS lookup issue.

Comment: The issue was that Firebase does not allow external calls from their functions without providing billing information. I have provided one and now intergration works fine! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, great! Glad you figured it out :)